# Oracle transaction to roll back all changes in a schema apart from 2 tables?

Tags: oracle, transactions, rollback, transactional

I'd like to set up an oracle transaction context where at the end of it I can roll back changes to all tables in a schema apart from 2.

The reason I want to do this is that I have a long and complicated piece of code written mostly in Java which writes and updates the DB but I want to make a 'read-only' version of it which I can execute for reporting purposes and want to write reporting information into 2 tables which should not be rolled back.

Comment: you can use `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` for this purpose. Place updates of those two tables in autonomous transaction and commit it. In that case you will be able to rollback all statment except that one, which was autonomous. More  [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/autonotransaction_pragma.htm)

Comment: In your procedure you can start with your 2 tables and make a COMMIT. Then continue with the other table which may be rolled back.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try :)

Comment: So I'd have to make a PL/SQL procedure for this and call it from Java correct?  Is there any way to do this direct from Java without having to write a PL/SQL procedure?